# Did the ancient Romans have a myth about returning to Rome?

Tags: classical-latin, roman-culture, passage-request, mythology

There is a modern myth (or perhaps rather folklore, superstition or something else) that if one throws a coin in Fontana di Trevi, faith will make them come back to Rome.
Was there anything similar in ancient Rome?
Any kind of belief, mythological story, myth, legend, folklore, or similar would be great, if someone can point to a suitable passage in the literature.
I am not sure how close to the modern fountain story ancient counterparts might come, so I will have to leave it somewhat open-ended.